Batch rename files by padding numeric part of filenames with leading zeros
I try to figure out how to batch rename files using Fish so that filenames like image1.png and image10.png will be replaced with image001.png and image010.png, that is, to pad numbers with leading zeros.
Here is what I have currently, after reading https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string.html#string-manipulate-strings:
for file in *; mv -- $file (string pad -c 0 -w 3 (string match -r '\d' $file)); end

Currently it only replaces filenames with 001 and 010.
To split filenames such as foo123.abc into foo, 123, and .abc groups, I can use the following regex: ([^\d]*)(\d+)(\..+).
But how to properly integrate this regex into the example I have posted above? How to make the example above work as described?

This will do it:
for file in *
    if string match --quiet --regex "(?s)(?<prefix>[^\d]+)(?<num>\d+)(?<suffix>.*)" -- $file
        mv -- $file "$prefix$(printf %03d $num)$suffix"
    end
end


In fish shell, you can get the subgroups of a regex match using named capture groups. The name of each group becomes a shell variable, whose value is the captured subgroup.
Here the regex has three capture groups prefix, num, and suffix, and these become ordinary shell variables.
Documentation on this feature.

Maybe better as (?s)(?<prefix>.*?)(?<!\d)(?<num>\d+)(?<suffix>.*) to also pad 0.jpg and avoid turning file1.mp3 into file1.mp003 (would still turn file.mp3 into file.mp003).

@StéphaneChazelas What works for me is (?s)(?<prefix>[^\d]+)?(?<num>\d+)(?<suffix>\..*). foo0.png -> foo000.png, 0.png -> 000.png, foo0.mp3 -> foo000.mp3, whereas foo.mp3 is unchanged.
